# Are immutable objects good practice?

Tags: c#, .net, immutability

Should I make my classes immutable where possible?

I once read the book "Effective Java" by Joshua Bloch and he recommended to make all business objects immutable for various reasons. (for example thread safety) 
Does this apply for C# too?

Do you try to make your objects immutable, so you have less problems when working with them?
Or is it not worth the inconvenience you have to create them?

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer to this question is "it depends". What does it depend on? A lot of factors, most of which are local to your project and not general in nature.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The immutable Eric Lippert has written a whole series of blog posts on the topic. Part one is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability).

Quoting from the [earlier post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/path-finding-using-a-in-c-3-0-part-two) that he links to:

> ASIDE: Immutable data structures are the way of the future in C#. It is much easier to reason about a data structure if you know that it will never change. Since they cannot be modified, they are automatically threadsafe. Since they cannot be modified, you can maintain a stack of past “snapshots” of the structure, and suddenly undo-redo implementations become trivial. On the down side, they do tend to chew up memory, but hey, that’s what garbage collection was invented for, so don’t sweat it.

Comment: Hm... Is immutable as a personal trait a positive or a negative thing? ;)

Comment: I highly doubt Eric is immutable. For one, I'm pretty sure changes in age can be observed.

Comment: Only if one considers the three-dimensional projection of his four-dimensional self onto the current time.

Comment: @Thomas, note however, that a name such as "Eric Lippert" can only identify this three-dimensional projection onto time, *not* the immutable four-dimensional self :-)

Comment: You are right, this is all very ambiguous. To be sure that we are talking about his projection for the same time coordinate, we should attach a SHA1 hash of his current state to his name, like so: "Eric Lippert@d998af36e8542af4ab858b7e69d54a8480b1ba39".

Comment: @Thomas, ah, so you mean *that* Eric Lippert?! Glad you clarified this - I was blindly assuming the whole time you were referring to Eric Lippert@d998af36e8542af4ab858b7e69d54a8480b1ba37 :-)

Comment: I'm not american nor "gangstah", but "Y'all" = "You're all", or? You gotta rewatch http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116126/ ;)

Comment: "Y'all are" would be "You all are," or in better form, "You are all".

Comment: Speaking of projections, ever noticed that streams effectively convert mutable objects into immutable ones? (e.g.: the user's keybaord input is an object with state, but if you work with it as an infinite stream, you can consider it to be an immutable object, and hence do functional programming with it. It's really neat!)

Comment: @Mehrdad: I wouldn't consider an object immutable if it gives a different answer for each invocation of `operator >>`. Certainly not (according to Eric's definition) observationally immutable, which is already a pretty weak form of immutability.

Comment: After reading Eric Lipperts articles, I wrote an article on immutable/mutable business data in C#. I think that it might be interesting in this context: http://rickyhelgesson.wordpress.com/2012/07/17/mutable-or-immutable-in-a-parallel-world/

Comment: @RickyHelgesson: There are two kinds of things which are easy to reason about: freely-shareable immutable things, or unshared mutable things.  Depending upon the nature of the business models you're using, I would suggest having a `MaybeMutableModel` class (or `IMaybeMutableModel` interface) from which both `ImmutableModel` and `MutableModel` derive; the class should include abstract `AsImmutable` and `AsMutable` members (which would cause an item to either return itself, or copy its data to one of proper mutability).  Most fields in the mutable class should be of `MaybeMutable...` types.

Comment: @RickyHelgesson: Using such an approach, if `Foo` is a MaybeMutable thing of unknown state, changing Foo.Bar.Boz would require setting `Foo=Foo.AsMutable()`, then `Foo.Bar=Foo.Bar.AsMutable()`, then `Foo.Bar.Boz=Foo.Bar.Boz.AsMutable()`, but one would avoid having to do anything with the branches of `Foo` that one wasn't mutating.  If one never shares things of MaybeMutable types without calling `AsImmutable` on them first, one would end up with shared immutable objects and unshared mutable ones--the perfect combination.  BTW, one other detail: I would suggest that each...

Comment: ...mutable object keep a cached reference to an immutable object, and immutable objects should override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, and should cache their hashcode value.  Calling `AsImmutable` on a mutable object should construct a new immutable object but then compare its value with that of the cached reference.  If they compare equal, return the cached instance; otherwise, replace the cache with the new instance and return that.  This will help ensure that repeated calls to `AsImmutable` that would return identical instances will return the same instance.

Comment: Link broke. Submitting an edit request to change to [MSDN archives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability) . I wish to remind the community that this is why you quote a link, and do not just supply the link. The *only* way I tracked this link down was googling the snippet Thomas quoted and sorting through results.

Comment: @JohnDoe Thank you for the edit! Shame on Microsoft for letting their links break like that. Quoting an entire series of blog posts is too much for SO though, and I did quote the part that more or less answers the question.

Answer (score 4):

This is going to be more of an opinion type answer but...

I find that the ease of understanding a program, i.e. maintaining and debugging said application, is inversly proportional to the amount of stateful transitions that occur during the processing of each component.  The less state I need to cart around in my head, the more focus I can pay attention to the logic within the algorithms as it is written.

Answer (score 2):

Immutable objects are the central feature of functional programming; it has its own advantages and disadvantages. (E.g. linked lists are practically impossible to be immutable, but immutable objects make parallelism a piece of cake.) So as a comment on your post noted, the answer is "it depends".

Comment: Singly-linked lists are pretty trivial to make immutable. Doubly-linked lists, on the other hand...

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head, I can't think of a reason for immutable objects making thread safe code somehow "better".

If I want an object to be thread safe, I will either put a lock around it or I will make a copy of it and update the reference once I'm done working on it. I typically wouldn't want a new object for every little change.

For me, immutable strings create more headaches for threading than it helps.

I actually went out of my way to make an "in-place" "ToUpper" using unsafe code isntead of the built in String.ToUpper(). It runs about 4 times faster and consumes 1/2 the peak memory.

Comment: _You_ put a lock around code to insure it's thread safe but can you guarantee every other developer on your team will do likewise?  Also can you guarantee that you won't forget a lock around an object which may be shared among threads?  Can you predict every object which might get shared by threads?  Just because you can't see a problem doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Another nice benefit of immutable structures is that you can locally cache instances of them and reuse them across multiple threads without fear of unexpected behaviors as would be the case if they were mutable.

For instance, suppose you are using an external caching service such as memcached or Velocity or some other equally simplistic distributed hashtable service. You could just use the C# client library and call it good enough. However, that is being wasteful with resources given a short-lived context like a web request scenario. What you really want is to pull each object from the cache once and only once in your context.

The safest way to get this job done is to place a local hashtable in your process in front of the cache provider. On the first request for the cache key you'd pull down the serialized byte stream that represents the object you wish to use and store that byte stream in your local hashtable. On subsequent requests for the same cache key, just look up the byte stream in the local hashtable and deserialize the object to a new instance for each request. This is to prevent multiple redundant trips to the cache server node for the same information that assumedly has not changed over the lifetime of your context.

With immutable structures, you could deserialize the byte stream only once on the first request and get away with storing the deserialized instance in the hashtable instead of the byte stream and just share that one single immutable instance of your object. This obviously cuts down on deserialization penalties which can add up rather quickly if your consuming code is written in such a fashion that it does not care how many calls it makes to the caching provider, assuming the cache is faster than querying your underlying data store.

Perhaps this is more of a subjective answer, but it's a specific problem that can be solved uniquely by using immutable structures so I thought it was relevant to share.

Comment: The volatility of your cached data is a concern here, but the assumption is that your "context" or "unit of work" is so short-lived that it doesn't make sense to constantly re-query your data from either your cache nodes or your underlying data store. Pulling it once should be sufficient to maintain a consistent view over the data for the short lifetime of the unit of work to be done to serve a single request, for instance. However, coding your business logic to ensure that each piece of data is queried only once is a difficult problem to solve and complicates your logic with mechanics.